# How do I pass a prop in front of map function in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, map-function

I'm importing some json files as :

```
import general from './Data/general.json';
import health from './Data/health.json';
import business from './Data/business.json';
```

And I am trying to iterate through an array "articles" in the json file, the names of the files are same as the category prop I'm passing. So, I want to know how can I change the file from which my map function takes data using prop inputs which change on press of buttons on the navbar.

Trying this, but it doesn't work:

`{props.category.articles.map((element) => {`

Doing this works but I can't change it according to the prop:

`{general.articles.map((element) => {`

I've tried enclosing props.category in { },( ), and passing them after declaring them in a const variable but none of it seems to work.

Comment: Where do you define `props`?  What "doesn't work" about this?  Can you update the question to include a [mcve] to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: By doesn't work I meant that props.category does not resolve to that particular prop value, ex:- if prop.category = entertainment, then I wanted it to be "entertainment.articles.map" similarly I wanted it to change based on the prop value I passed. I basically wanted it to be like a dynamic JS expression so I can change value using props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
  const data = {general,health,business};

  {data[props.category].ariticles.map(...)}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it made my program work